# How do I determine the harshad value of a number with a function?

Tags: python, function, sum, boolean

So far I have:

```
n=int(input("Enter a number:"))
tot=0
while(n>0):
        dig=n%10
        tot=tot+dig
        n=n//10
        print("sum is",tot)
def Harshad(tot):
        if n%tot ==0:
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

This gives me the sum of the integers, then I want to see if the number entered is divisible my the summation of the integers, i.e. 81 is a harshad number, since it is divisible by the summation of its numbers: 8+1=9,
81 / 9 = 9 Thus, no remainder.
However I never get the "true" or "false" output and I am wondering why that is. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How are you calling the Harshad function?  That function _returns_ true/false but it doesn't _print_ anything; the caller would have to capture the returned value and print it.

Comment: ah okay thank you, how would i have to do it for the function to return true/false in the terminal for the user to see? so that if per we they entered the number 81, that the output would be “true”

Answer (score 0):

```
n=int(input("Enter a number: "))

def Harshad(tot):
    print(n)
        if n%tot == 0:
            return True
        else:
            return False

tot=0
temp_n = n  # Use a different variable for your loop
while(temp_n>0):
        dig=temp_n%10
        tot=tot+dig
        temp_n=temp_n//10
        print("sum is",tot)

ret_value = Harshad(tot)    # Call the function and store its return value
print("Number is Harshad: ", ret_value) # Print return value
```